# Скомпилировать программу вместе с библиотеками в один файл

Tags: c++, linux, c, gcc

мне нужно сделать чтоб программа не требовала библиотеки в системе, но нормально работала. Не хотелось бы пересобирать библиотеки

ОС: Linux

Компилятор: gcc

Comment: Какие именно библиотеки? Вообще все? В теории нужно просто добавить `-static`, но на практике это так просто не делается, поэтому нужны всякие https://appimage.org/ , https://flatpak.org/ , snap, и т.д.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я думаю или  libcurl или libsdl2

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб собрать одновайловый (статический) вариант программы в первую очередь нужны объекты библиотеки для статической линковки. Заканчивается на `*.a` имя файла.

В дистрибутивах обычно этих файлов нет. Для того чтоб их получить понадобится пересобрать библиотеки с параметром `-static`, обычно через `./configure --disable-shared`

Как именно собрать зависит от конкретной библиотеки.

Вот Qt5 пересобирается около 2х суток...